# how to display simple_format in rails 3 with color text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i am new to ruby on rails . 
In my html view page i have local variable `@text` as formatted text

```
@text = "<p><span style=\"background-color: #99cc00;\">asd as
  <span style=\"color: #ff0000;\">welcome </span></span></p>"

<%= simple_format @text %>
```

It is showing only text with black color . Please give some suggestion

Comment: So the problem is that some of your styles are being lost? Can you explain what you are trying to achieve? You can probably do this without using `simple_format`.

Comment: instead just do: `<%= @text.html_safe %>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`simple_format` is used to apply HTML formatting to plain text, e.g. replacing newline with `<br>`.

To render an already HTML formatted string, use `html_safe`:

```
@text = "<p>...</p>".html_safe # this tells Rails not to escape your HTML
```

In your view:

```
<%= @text %>
```

Comment: Important Caveat:  consider whether `@text` will be user generated - if so, do not call html_safe on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
<%= "<p><span style=\"background-color: #99cc00;\"> {@text.html_safe} <span style=\"color: #ff0000;\">welcome </span></span></p>" %>
```